# Solution for simple JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hope everyone is well. I have created this simple JS function but I am not understanding why it's not working. The function name is correctly given and JS was working strangely. There are all P tags inside HTML and JS is only 2 line describing the color after a click. But only the first P tag is getting colored and the correct is getting colored. But 3 and 4 was blank why? is there any CSS solution for that? I have tried visited: and focus: on CSS don't work in a p tag.
here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Question 1</p>
<p id="wrong" onclick="myFunction()">1. Ans 1 </p>
<p id="correct" onclick="myFunction()">2. Ans 2</p>
<p id="wrong" onclick="myFunction()">3. Ans 3</p>
<p id="wrong" onclick="myFunction()">4. Ans 4</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("wrong").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("correct").style.color = "green";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have duplicated the ID `wrong` in your markup.

Comment: so 1 id is for 1 tag only?

Comment: Yes. You should be using classes instead.

Comment: It's now working.. Thanks, man!

Comment: can I use same class multiple time as
``` 
document.getElementByClass("wrong1").style.color = "red"; 

```

Comment: yes but while accessing you need to do it in this way  ``` document.getElementByClass("wrong")[0].style.color = "red"; ```

Comment: for accessing Ans 3 it can be ``` document.getElementByClass("wrong")[2].style.color = "red"; ```

Comment: can you explain [0] and as I am using it multiple times should it increase like [1] [2]?

Comment: @Rafin because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` object. It is some kind of array that has all the nodes having the `.wrong` class. You can access each node with index, or iterate through it with `for` or `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already commented, you should never have duplicate `id` in your markup. You must change to using class instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quiz page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Question 1</p>
  <p class="wrong" onclick="myFunction()">1. Ans 1 </p>
  <p class="correct" onclick="myFunction()">2. Ans 2</p>
  <p class="wrong" onclick="myFunction()">3. Ans 3</p>
  <p class="wrong" onclick="myFunction()">4. Ans 4</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.wrong').forEach(el => {
        el.style.color = 'red'
      })

      document.querySelectorAll('.correct').forEach(el => {
        el.style.color = 'green'
      })
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks